# Census Goecoding Issue

Tags: python, geocoding, census

I am trying to do a simple geocode operation that I have been able to do many times in the past. This simple code no longer works, because it returns this output.
{'States': [], 'Counties': [], '2020 Census Blocks': [], 'Census Tracts': []}. What could possibly explain this? I have run this code many times in the past and I have never seen this before.

```
import censusgeocode as cg
census = cg.coordinates(x=40.81918, y=-83.29061)
census
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is the longitude and `y` is the latitude. You need to swap them, like this:

```
census = cg.coordinates(x=-83.29061, y=40.81918)
```

From the [Geocoding Services Web Application Programming Interface (API)](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf):

> `x,y (searchtype = coordinates)` – The longitude and latitude represented as
> decimal x/y values. Only returns geoLookup data. Can only be used with returntype =
> geographies.